# How to add Content Security Policy headers for login page in Spring Security xml configuration?

Tags: authentication, tomcat, spring-security, content-security-policy

I am trying to add Content Security Policy header property for all security filters in my Spring web app, I am being able to add them using `headers` element tag in `http` element of [Spring Security](http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd) for generic security filter, but for security filters of login page, css etc, I am not being able to add them as [Spring Security](http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd) doesn't allow any element inside an `http` tag if its `security` tag is set to "none". Also If I doesn't set it to "none" (to add the required headers) the web app doesn't compile properly giving "not configured for login-page" error. Following is the configuration I am using right now:

```
  <http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
  <http pattern="/login.jsp*" security="none"/>

  <http auto-config='true'>
     <security:headers>
        <security:header name="X-Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'"/>
        <security:header name="X-WebKit-CSP" value="default-src 'self'"/>
     </security:headers>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page='/login.jsp'/>
  </http>
```

How should I resolve this, I am using [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-minimal) documentation. Thank you. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to implement and register an `HandlerInterceptor`  which intercepts the HTTP requests.

And then use this interceptor to add the additional HTTP headers.

(You already can find a lot of questions about HTTP request interception on SO)